# Bing Maps API Web Control, Which directions are selected?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

Using the bing maps API Web Control v8's DirectionsManager, how can I tell which directions have been selected if there are multiple routes displayed? Is there an event that I can't seem to find? Or maybe something that I can get from the directionsManager object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the update event and the getCurrentRoute function:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function () {
    var currentRoute = directionsManager.getCurrentRoute();

    //This will be the currently displayed route. This will fire after a route calculation or when you select an alternate route option.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius :)